# Powershell move output of loop into Array

Tags: powershell

It seems like a simple answer but for the life of me I cant figure it out. What I am trying to do is get a bunch of email addresses out of a text file and strip out the bit of the email past the @ (e.g if the email address was adam@home.com I am interested in the adam bit).

The script below outputs the values that I want however I would like to have the output written into a array rather than to the console. What would be the best way of doing this?

Code below, thanks.

```
# Import the text file into a variable 
$import = Get-Content c:\\temp\test.txt
# Variable to hold total number of emails
$totalEmails = $import.Count
#Variable to run loop
$start = 0
#Used as a separator to look at the first part of the email address
$separator = "@"
# Will increment by two to show the first part of the array in parts which     holds the text before the @ 
$even = 0
# Username after @
$userName


#Strip out the text before the @
do {

    $parts = $import.split($separator)
    $even+=2

    # This line here is whats not working, I would like to have the output of     each echo written into the array $userName 
    $userName = echo $parts[$even]


    $start++

} while ($totalEmails -gt $start)
```

Comment: This replaces your whole script: `$array = Get-Content "C:/temp/test.txt" | % {$_ | Split-String -Separator "@" | Select -First 1}` Get a look at [about_Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response! I tried to run this but it errors on the Split-String statement?

Comment: Sure? What's the error?

Comment: @Clijsters Bet its `split-string : The term 'split-string' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,`

Comment: There isn't a Split-String cmdlet.

Comment: @EBGreen: As this is not 100% wrong, it's even not right. It's part of the Pscx. I forgot about that, sorry. But there is a `-split` operator.

Comment: You're right. I should have said that there isn't one in the core cmdlets.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your email parsing doesn't make a  whole lot of sense.  Here's a one-liner for your question:

```
$Arr = @(Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\test.txt') -replace '@.+'
```

Comment: This done the trick, thank you very much! Just so I can understand what exactly I have done, the statement of "-replace '@.+'" is that just cutting off the rest of the text after the @?

Comment: Yes, it is replacing the @ character and every character after it with the empty string ''

Comment: It doesn't really apply in this case since the regex is simple, but I rarely pass on an opportunity to use one of my favorite quotes: ***"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski***

Comment: @MrI The regex translates to: literal @ character, wildcard character 1+.  So, @ and everything until end of line and by omitting the second argument, it gets deleted.